# Multiple Tables With Same Structure Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We have a database with multiple tables with Same structure

## Table 1

Key ID ........

## Table 2

Key ID .......

The number of tables can be dynamic based on configuration.

I am trying to upgrade the data access Layer to Entity framework. I have created one class representing the structure of the table. My Plan is to use the same class for all the tables with same structure. Bubt I could not find enough information on how to do this. What I understood is that I can map one class to one table only.

Is there any way to achieve this using entity framework?

Comment: Why not normalise your database tables instead?

Comment: Create a single view for all tables with the same structure. Map the EF entity to this view.

Comment: @IntoNET:The database is quite complicated and this can not be changed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easy way: have an abstract base class with all the properties, and map concrete types:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string StringField { get; set; }
   /* Other fields */ 
}

[Table("Table1")]
public class Table1 : BaseClass
{
}

[Table("Table2")]
public class Table2 : BaseClass
{
}
```

I'm not answering whether that design is good or bad (I wouldn't say I like it as you explained it), I'm just answering the question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try this.

Comment: I've settled on doing this but with an interface instead of an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

And now for a completely different approach which I have used successfully in EF Core:

Create a parameterized stored procedure which uses some dynamic SQL to return the actual table you want and use the FromSql feature.