# .NET: Entity Framework & DbContext: Use same model/class for multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am creating a new project on top of an existing database which I cannot modify - the database design unfortunately is rather poor in some aspects. However, amongst others this database has eight tables that have the same structure. For the sake of simplicity of this question, let's assume it is two tables, Table1 and Table2 with a very limited set of fields. It is an Azure SQL database in case that matters.

**Note:** This question was highlighted as a duplicate [of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372618/multiple-tables-with-same-structure-entity-framework) but I don't believe it is. I am not interested in how to get around this problem or solve it (I have suggested a solution), I want to know why it appears in the first place.

In my database context, this looks like this:

```
    public virtual DbSet<Table1> Table1{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Table2> Table2{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PkId);

            entity.ToTable("table1");

            entity.Property(e => e.PkId).HasColumnName("pk_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Version1)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("version1");
            }

        modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PkId);

            entity.ToTable("table2");

            entity.Property(e => e.PkId).HasColumnName("pk_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Version2)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("version2");
            }
    }
```

Note that the field names are slightly different. Now I thought I was super smart when I decided to simplify this code by using the same model for these two classes - as this would simplify my code a lot.

```
    public virtual DbSet<Table> Table1{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Table> Table2{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PkId);

            entity.ToTable("table1");

            entity.Property(e => e.PkId).HasColumnName("pk_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("version1");
            }

        modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PkId);

            entity.ToTable("table2");

            entity.Property(e => e.PkId).HasColumnName("pk_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("version2");
            }
    }
```

Generally, this seems to work, but when running `AddRangeAsync()` on one of the table, it silently fails - nothing is written to the database when calling `SaveChangesAsync()`.

I found myself a way around this by using AutoMapper: Basically I work with my `Table` objects, and just before adding them to the DB Context I map them to their respective target objects, e.g. Table1. This works without any problems and is a proper way around this issue.

However, I'm still curious to know why my ingenious solution silently fails - I was quite convinced that you could use the same model class for different tables. Is it the modelBuilder that cannot handle the same entity type multiple times? Is there a better way than using AutoMapper to handle situations like that? I thought I could avoid the mapping process for performance reasons and the sake of simplicity.

Again, I cannot modify the database design, if it was my DB I would have used one table and introduced an additional ID column or sth like that, but I cannot do that - don't blame me for the poor DB design.

Comment: I would have to do some proper testing to know for sure but in that `OnModelCreating` method, you are mapping the `Table` entity twice. I would guess that either the second one replaces the first and you actually wrote data to the wrong table or else it fails because it finds two mappings for the same entity and doesn't know what to do. Note that those mappings are for the entity, not the table, so you need two separate entities if you want two useful mappings. Maybe using a common base class for two separate entities with no extra properties is the best solution.

Comment: As a side note: "amongst others this database has eight tables that have the same structure." - If these tables represents the same entity then it is truly a poor design. However, if they represent different entities that just happen to have similar properties, then there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Tables With Same Structure Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372618/multiple-tables-with-same-structure-entity-framework)

Comment: EF Core, like all ORMs, deals with *objects* not tables. A DbSet is a Repository for a specific Object Type, not a table. What is the relation between *objects* in your application? And why are there multiple tables in the database? What's the relation?

Comment: If the tables hold different types of data they can be modeled using [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) with eg Table-per-Concrete type and a *single* DbSet. You can ask for specific types in LINQ with `OfType`, because EF works with objects, not tables. If manual partitioning was used - why not use SQL Server's built-in automatic partitioning, which is available in all versions and editions? Multitenancy can be handled with interceptors.

Comment: Another option is to map one DbSet to a view that uses `UNION ALL` to combine all tables. If proper constraints are used on the tables, SQL Server will be able to identify which table to use for both reads and saves.

Comment: What type of "common" code you are trying to simplify? Do you ever need polymorphic query (which returns all the records from all these tables)? If not, simply make your `Table1`, `Table2` etc. **entity** classes inherit `Table` **base class**. No need of TPC or other EFC inheritance strategies, just reusing the common structure (properties/fields) of the base class. e.g. `public Table1 : Table { }`, then `modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>(entity =>...)`. Same for `Table2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general EF Core uses the entity class CLR type as identity of a separate entity, thus the associated database table or view, columns, relationships etc. - see [Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations). It can be seen from many generic methods of the `DbContext` having `TEntity` generic type argument, or even non generic methods like `Attach`, `Add` etc. just receiving object instance, and using the `GetType()` for finding `IEntityType` in the model, and in turn provide the entity CRUD services. But most noticeable is the `Set<TEntity>()` method used to retrieve/query the entity data from the corresponding table. Even only the presence of that method is clear indication that the entity CLR type and table   relationship is one to one (if speaking in relational database terms).

Now, in latest versions in theory EF Core also supports the so called [Shared-type entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#shared-type-entity-types) which are used for implementing the automatic join entity for many-to-many with artificial `Dictionary<string, object>` "entity", but could be be used with user defined types as well. The problem is though, they require special configuration providing a name for the entity, and then passing that name for different methods (including aforementioned `Set<TEntity>`()), and some other which receive just object instances do not work at all. Because of all that, I find them not very practical usable.

With that in mind, it's much better the use a base class (with or without any EF Core database inheritance mapping) and empty derived (but separate) types. In your example, you would have a base class `Table` and derived classes `Table1 : Table`, `Table2 : Table` etc. It's similar to workaround you mentioned, but does not require AutoMapper (or similar mapper).

Finally, what's wrong with your attempt. Well, code wise it's ok, also there is no EF Core fluent mapping bug, so what's the problem then.

The problem is that EF Core fluent API allow you multiple table/attribute *redefinition*, with later simply overriding the previous configuration (last wins). So here

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.PkId);

    entity.ToTable("table1");

    entity.Property(e => e.PkId).HasColumnName("pk_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.Version)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasColumnName("version1");
    }

modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.PkId);

    entity.ToTable("table2");

    entity.Property(e => e.PkId).HasColumnName("pk_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.Version)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasColumnName("version2");
}
```

you are effectively mapping entity `Table` to table "table2" with `Version` column mapped to "version2" column etc. Essentially everything from the first configuration is ignored/replaced by the second. You can easily verify that by generating EF Core migration from the above model/fluent configuration, and you'll see that there would be just one `CreateTable` instead of 2,3,4 you expect.

What about

```cs
    public virtual DbSet<Table> Table1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Table> Table2 { get; set; }
```

think of them (and what you'll get actually) as two variables pointing to one and the same list/object/definition, in this case - table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in depth explanation!